# Passing JSON to Web.API works with Fiddler but not in code

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass my JSON to Web.API service. The sending works well with Fiddler when I set to POST and I get value inside `[FromBody ]` argument:

```
Http/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: http://localhost:27701/api/myList
Content-Length: 883
```

But when I use this C# code to post JSON, then `[FromBody ]` argument is empty:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(data);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:27701/api/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("myList", content).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
    s = result;
}
```

The data part is the exact JSON in both Fiddler and my code and the controller called in both calls.

This is my JSON:

```
{  
  "Id":0,
  "Count":0,
  "StartDate":"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/",
  "Address":{  
    "Id":0,
    "State":"test",
    "City":"test"
  }
}
```

One thing is if I don't put `'` (single quotation) in both side of string inside fiddler the `[FromBody]` argument is empty, but if i put those on C# sample the respond is 500 server error.

Comment: Can you add receiving Web.API method code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted your receiving method code, but based on provided data it should be a method with one argument which is an object that represents your JSON. In this case you don't need to use `FromBody` attribute at all.

If you check this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) you can find there that:

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value    from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>     bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>     and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from 
>     a string.
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message    body, using a media-type formatter.

I created a models based on your JSON:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; } // Keeped as string for simplicity
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

And then really simple method that can receive such JSON:

```
public RootObject Post(RootObject req)
{
    return req;
}
```

Then I tested it both with Fiddler:

```
Method: 
  POST
Headers:
  Content-Type: application/json
Request Body:
  {"Id":0,"Count":0,"StartDate":"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/","Address":{"Id":0,"State":"test","City":"test"}}
```

And C# code:

```
var data = "{\"Id\":0,\"Count\":0,\"StartDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"Address\":{\"Id\":0,\"State\":\"test\",\"City\":\"test\"}}";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(data);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response =
        client.PostAsync("http://my.url", content).Result;
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

In both cases I was able to get sent object back.

Some tips:

- When you send JSON with Fiddler you should **not** use any escaping
  for request body. Just enter valid JSON and that's it.
- In C# code if you need to declare a string variable with JSON you
  will need to use escaping. For example `var json = "\"a\":\"b\"";` or
  `var json = @"""a"":""b""";`. If you received JSON from somewhere
  else then you don't need to do nothing.
- You should never encase JSON with `'` chars.

Comment: thanks man that was the problem. when i changed my web api post method to this :
public string Post([FromBody]MyObjectModel value)
 , it works fine.